# Cron Jobs on GAE with PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cron

I have a php file that runs fine from a web browser but fails as cron job.

My cron.yaml includes:

```
cron:
- description: new stuff
  url: /crontest
  schedule: every 1 hours
```

and app.yaml has:

```
handlers:
- url: /crontest
  script: crontest.php
  login: admin
```

Any extra requirements needed in my php file?

Answer (score 1):

So versions, or "target" is key in cron.yaml if you have multiple versions with different code.